# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una fila de una tabla en HTML y que cambie de color al dar clic y que se quede con ese color al recargar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo una tabla en html, pero deseo seleccionar solo la fila y cuando de clic cambie de color y que se quede seleccionado cuando recargue o cambie de página, alguien puede ayudarme? Adjunto el código que tengo.

```
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('row-selected')) {
      $(this).addClass('other-clic')
    } else {
      cleanTr()
      $(this).addClass('row-selected')
    }
  })

  function cleanTr() {
    $('.row-selected').each(function(index, element) {
      $(element).removeClass('row-selected')
      $(element).removeClass('other-clic')
    })
  }
})



.row-selected {
  background: yellow;
}

tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="default">
  <thead>
    <th>Proyecto</th>
    <th>N1</th>
    <th>N2</th>
    <th>N3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>APROBADOS</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>RECHAZADOS</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>EN ANÁLISIS</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>EN ESPERA</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
      <th>0</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola intenta redactar mejor tu pregunta para que recibas ayuda, te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tengas mas ayuda

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) ahi hay un ejemplo crea una cookie 1 y luego recarga la pagina y muestra tus cookies veras que aun sigue la cookie 1

Answer (score 1):

Es imposible guardar estados en HTML + CSS + JS sin usar cookies o algun tipo de storage. Echa un vistazo a https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

El tema sería en el mismo momento que cambias el color de la fila, guardas el indice de la fila en el storage i cada vez que cargas la página, compruebas si existe en el storage el indice y por lo tanto, pintas la fila.